# Crystal report does not accept user's printer settings

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm a C# developer and I need to use Crystal Report for my editions.

The problem is that it only prints in portrait. When I try to change the print settings, they are ignored. If, for example, I choose "landscape" in the printer settings, it will still print in portrait.

[image]

I've found a lot of topics about this but no working answer. In particular, I saw that you could uncheck "optimized for display", but that doesn't change anything.

I tried to cheat by creating a "print" button and coding it myself to force the parameters:

```
private void OnPrintButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog PrintD = new PrintDialog();
    Nullable<Boolean> print = false;
    try
    {
        print = PrintD.ShowDialog();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Imprimante non trouvée: " + exc.Message, "Erreur");
    }

    if (print == true)
    {
        PrintQueue printQueue = PrintD.PrintQueue;
        report.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printQueue.FullName;
        Debug.WriteLine("Printer Name: " + printQueue.FullName);
        System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings printerSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
        printerSettings.PrinterName = printQueue.FullName;
        report.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

It works on most printers, but today I have a problem with a client where printing causes a "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: invalid printer name" error.

The ideal would be for the application to work "natively" with the settings the user chooses, without having to force anything, I guess.

I'm on CR 13.0.22 and I've run out of ideas.

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility that the printer driver could be overriding the printer parameters and forcing the orientation?  This wouldn't solve the error with your printer selection in code, but if you can fix the orientation problem, you may not need the code that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you can get Page Orientation from print dialog with `PrintD.PrintTicket.PageOrientation`.

How about setting this value to `report.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation` before calling `PrintToPrinter` function.

Here is a code example below that you might try.

```
if (print == true)
{
    PrintQueue printQueue = PrintD.PrintQueue;
    report.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printQueue.FullName;
    System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings printerSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
    printerSettings.PrinterName = printQueue.FullName;

    var orientation = PrintD.PrintTicket.PageOrientation;

    if (orientation == PageOrientation.Landscape)
    {
        report.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperOrientation.Landscape;
    }

    if (orientation == PageOrientation.Portrait)
    {
        report.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperOrientation.Portrait;
    }

    report.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following if you haven't already? Open the report from Crystal Reports application, go to File - Page Settings - and set the page to Landscape, then save the rpt (and deploy it wherever the rpt for your application is located).